# Returning a static HTML file with # fragment pointing to an <section> element

Tags: python, html, url-routing, bottle

Say a website www.example.com has a  with id="section_two". This section is offscreen. I can make this website load with this section onscreen by calling the URL www.example.com#section_two.

Now, say I'm trying to return a static index.html file using Bottle.py, but specifically I'm trying to return it with a  onscreen that would otherwise offscreen. How can I return a URL of the form www.example.com#section_two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want a user to receive a html page already scrolled to the necessary section? It is not possible without some in-browser JavaScript. You can add something like this to your html (with JQuery):

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#section_two').get(0).scrollIntoView(); 
    });
  </script>
</head>
```